# Swift LazyMapCollection method reduce

Tags: swift, swift2

Can someone describe what actually this operation does. As I understood that it is a map, but what does actually `values` and `reduce` mean. And as I understood it took closure as a parameter right?

```
let result = self.myDictionary.values.reduce(0) { (count, objectInMyDictionary) in
        return count + objectInMyDictionary.totalObjects
}
```

Let's suppose that I have a dictionary:

```
["key1": Object1]
["key2": Object1]
["key3": Object1]
...
```

As I understood this method above will work as an iterator over all objects in myDictionary. So actually I can do this via cycle I guess and result will be the same. What is the difference and what is advantage of this booth approaches. Sorry I am new in Swift.

```
let count : Int = 0
for (_, objectInMyDictionary) in self.myDictionary {
      count += objectInMyDictionary.totalObjects
}
```

Comment: In your second example it should be `var count : Int = 0` so that `count` is mutable.

Answer (score 3):

All four sequence iteration methods — `map` (and `flatMap`), `forEach`, `filter`, and `reduce` — do things that theoretically and practically you *could* do by writing your own iteration using `for in`. And `for in` itself can always be expanded to be expressible with `while` and the generator.

But just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *want* to. Having these methods is convenient and arguably makes for far greater clarity, and turns an imperative operation into a functional one.

[Consider that the `reduce` version of your example is a one-liner whose *result* is the answer as a constant, whereas the `for` version requires that variable storage be set aside beforehand. If you don't see that the `for` version is just plain clunky, well, for people who like that kind of thing, that is the kind of thing they like.]

Also, the iteration methods are obviously far more general, since *any* function (of the appropriate form) can be plugged into them. They simply encapsulate a common need.

Comment: And please consider reading [The Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) if you never have. You'll be functional-programming until it comes out of your ears! :)

Comment: Perhaps also worth noting that all of the collections methods mentioned can be written in terms of `reduce` :)